# SMB user is owner of directory but it is using group permission

Tags: linux, permissions, samba

### Rewording:

I have a directory with permission `755`, shared using samba. I have a samba user `abc:abc` which is also the owner of that directory. Windows samba client was denied write to the directory. When I chmod the directory to `775`, the windows client is now able to write in it.

From the above, I have the conclusion that directory is checking samba user's group permission even though said user is the owner of the directory. Why is it?

*Original details:*

---

Apologize if I have any typo, I am typing it from air.

`drwxr-xr-x   abc  abc  4096  DirectoryName`

I have `smb.conf` sharing it.

`[something]
   comment = something
   browseable = yes
   path = /something/something
   guest ok = no
   read only = no
   create mask = 0775
   valid user = abc`

On windows 10, I used user abc to access the samba share. I notice that I don't have permission to write to the folder. It is weird to me because `abc` is the owner of the directory and it should have full access. I changed the permission with chmod 775 and `abc` can now write so I have the conclusion that it is using the group permission to access instead.

Why is it? I thought owner permission has priority over group. Is this how it works or just how samba handles permission?

Also is `directory mask` needed in smb.conf? How is it different from the directory permission itself?

Comment: If you create a file which owner does it have?

Comment: With `chmod 775 ./` I created file & directory. Both show the smb user as owner and group. Weirdly the file has 766 even though I have `create mask = 0775` but that's another question.  I set it back to `chmod 755 ./` and I am unable to create file nor directory.

Comment: Without Samba: Can the user create files there directly under Linux?

Comment: Yes. I just tried logging in linux using that user and successfully touched a file with the directory permission 755.

Comment: You could set the samba logging level to maximum. Maybe the logs tell you then what's up.

Answer (score 3):

If you do not configure `directory mask` then a default value is used. This value is equivalent to the `umask` of a process. It affects the permissions of newly created directories.

A new directory has these permissions:

directory mask 000

000

directory mask 755

755

directory mask 777

777

Comment: I thought `create mask = 777` is used to set permission of new files/directories. Instead of `directory mask`

Comment: @Alf `create mask` is for files, `directory mask` is for directories.

Comment: Well noted. I'll include that as well.

Answer (score 0):

I just experienced these exact symptoms.  Centos 8, Samba 4.11.2.  Turned out to be a problematic cache.  I adapted command lines (as superuser, naturally) found on [this Kombitz page](https://www.kombitz.com/2019/03/13/how-to-clear-samba-and-winbind-cache/) for my specific setup as follows:

```
systemctl stop nmb
systemctl stop smb
net cache flush
cd /var/lib/samba
rm *.tdb
systemctl start nmb
systemctl start smb
```

After doing this, the problem went away; Samba began correctly applying user permissions instead of the user's group permissions.  Reboot wasn't necessary.